# Custom Rails routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a model called `appointment` and I want to change the way the "new" page works. When the user clicks a certain hour slot on the calendar, I want the user to be taken to a page with a URL like this:

```
appointment/new/hour/10
```

This would take the user to the "new" page and the time for the appointment would be pre-populated at 10:00am.

I'm familiar with symfony routing but I find Rails routing a little bit confusing. Specifically, I don't know how to write my `link_to` function call in such a way that it will give me a URL like the one above.

I've R'd some of the FM but I didn't find a place that goes over the kind of thing I want to do. If someone could either explain how to do what I'm trying to do or simply point me to the pertinent documentation, that would be awesome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your routes.rb you could create a route such as:

```
# Rails 3
match 'appointment/new/hour/:hour' => "appointments#new", :as => :new_appointment_with_time

# Rails 2
map.new_appointment_with_time 'appointment/new/hour/:hour', :controller => "appointments", :action => "new"
```

Then, you can use it in links:

```
link_to "10am", new_appointment_with_time_path(:hour => 10)
```

In the controller, you can retrieve the value and make your new appointment instance use it using `params[:hour]`:

```
@appointment = Appointment.new(:hour => params[:hour])
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer! That worked perfectly. Interestingly, the time in my form's drop-down is off my a certain number of hours, but I suppose that's a separate problem.